# Include @font-face with save page as

Tags: html, css

I can embed a custom font with @font-face in the css like this:

```
@font-face{ font-family: MyFont; src: url('fonts/font.ttf'); }
```

But when I save the page on my computer to see the page as local, the font is not saved.
I tried this with Firefox and Chrome and the issue is the same in both.

How can I force embed the font with `save page as` ?

Comment: this might go under superuser.  depends on where your looking for the resolution.

Comment: Agreed - not only do I think this will be browser / OS specific and next to impossible to force for everyone... I think it's also better suited for SU.

Comment: Save Page As won't know how to follow url(); in CSS. You'll need to grab those files manually.

Comment: @LuckySpoon: As the browser can read that `url` stuff from CSS, it could also save it. That's not really an argument you give.

Comment: Which browser are you saving the file with?

Comment: @hakre: In my experience, Save Page As _does not_ reliably follow CSS paths. Whilst I agree it _should_ know how, I've never found this to be the case.

Comment: This should be reported in the issue trackers of those browsers.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily done with the command line tool wget. [Download it](http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions?action=show&redirect=Faq#download) and then enter in your command line:

```
wget -p -k http://mywebsite.com
```

Wget will download all CSS, JS and Webfonts.

Comment: If you do this you might need to remove all the query parameters from the saved files, todo this on UNIX use something like `find . -name \*\\?\* | while read file; do  mv "$file" $(echo $file | sed 's/\?.*//'); done`